# QFile does not create file on mac

Tags: qt

I use this code (this is qt sample)

```
QFile file("out.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

QTextStream out(&file);
out << "The magic number is: " << 49 << "\n";
```

I cant find file "out.txt" on mac. How to fix it?

Comment: Where are you looking for it? From the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#QFile): 'If the file name has no path or a relative path, the path used will be the application's current directory path at the time of the open() call.'

Comment: Can you print out file.errorString() after open as well as write? `if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) qDebug() << "Failed to open:" << file.errorString();` for starter. Also, a dabhaid was giving the hint: how are you running the application and where are you looking for the file?

Answer (score 1):

Several Problems here :

Firstly you are not checking what is the return value of `file.open()`.
Only if true will it actually create the file.
Also relative path so the file will be created at the application working directory when you call the open() method.
Also you will need write permission for the user in the directory for the file to be created.

You can check error stream for any errors that it will throw.

Answer (score 1):

The file is writing to your apps package contents sitting next to the executable..

yourApp/Contents/MacOS/out.txt

I don't know how to get a file to write outside of the package contents though..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

On the line:
QFile file("out.txt");

You need to specify all the root on mac!!

Answer (score 0):

You should check your home directory. It should be there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28545766)

Comment: File will appear in home directory.